# Can't use post method on REST_API Codeigniter

Tags: rest, codeigniter

This is my code:

```
require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
class Login extends REST_Controller
{
    function __construct($config = 'rest')
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    public function index_post()
    {
        echo "Post";
    }
    public function index_get()
    {
        echo "Get";
    }
}
```

But I use Postman to test:
[When I use Post method:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4RZf.png)
[When I use Get method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URzHk.png)

I use different method, but it work only with **index_get**. If I remove function **index_get** and use post method on Postman, it will be **unknow method**.
How to fix it? I need use post method.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the same function name, change the function name. It might be different(_post,_get) while you are coding, But when you are accessing through url you have to remove the method(_post,_get) which means both are of same function name. So it returns the first function return value

Comment: I don't understand. Can you guide me?

Comment: @bergin what do you mean with that ? his controller is perfectly fine, there are two different `index` methods `index_post` and `index_get` which are reacting based on the requested http type...